# File access denied based on file extension

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2019

I'm facing a strange "Access denied" issue when I try to open a file in my C# (.NET Framework 4.8) application: the error appears only with some file extension, in particular with .txt and .csv, while other extensions (.log, .json, even .dll or .aaa) can be read fine.
The issue appears only on a Windows Server 2019 standard while on my Windows 11 dev environment everything is good.
I'm using `File.ReadAllText` function, but even with `StreamReader` or if I try to move file the access denied appears.

I'm sure that is not a real permission issue:

- I'm machine admin and even running application "as administrator" is the same
- folder and files have full permission to "Everyone"
- all files are exactly the same (starting from a txt containing simply "SOME TEXT"), copied and renamed with different extensions
- I can work with all files: open using notepad, edit save, move, rename etc

I build a very simple form application with two buttons:

- I first load file list from a folder into a listBox
- I load the selected file into another textbox
- I wrote messages into a log textbox

```
private void buttonList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        listBoxFileList.Items.Clear();
        List<FileInfo> files = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxLoadFolder.Text)
                    .GetFiles(textBoxfilemask.Text)
                    .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
                    .ToList();
        textBox1Log.Text += $@"File list loaded{Environment.NewLine}";
        textBox1Log.Text += $@" -> found {files.Count} files{Environment.NewLine}";

        files.ForEach(file =>
        {
            listBoxFileList.Items.Add(file.FullName);
            textBox1Log.Text += $@" -> available file: {file.Name}{Environment.NewLine}";
        });
        

    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        textBox1Log.Text += $@"ERROR loadin file list: {ex.Message}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }
}

private void buttonReadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxFileContent.Text = "";
    if (!(listBoxFileList.SelectedItem is null))
    {
        string selectedFile = listBoxFileList.SelectedItem as string;
        try
        {
            textBox1Log.Text += $@"selected file: {selectedFile}{Environment.NewLine}";
            textBox1Log.Text += $@"reading content....{Environment.NewLine}";
            textBoxFileContent.Text = File.ReadAllText(selectedFile);
            textBox1Log.Text += $@"Done....{Environment.NewLine}";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1Log.Text += $@"ERROR loading file {selectedFile}: {ex.Message}{Environment.NewLine}";
        }
    }
    else
        textBox1Log.Text += $@"WARNING No file selected{Environment.NewLine}";
}
```

EDIT:
removed the image, here the log output:

```
File list loaded
 -> found 7 files
 -> available file: RGP.txt
 -> available file: RGP.csv
 -> available file: RGP.dll
 -> available file: RGP.log
 -> available file: RGP.aaa
 -> available file: RGP.dat
 -> available file: RGP.json
selected file: C:\ToLoad\RGP.log
reading content....
Done....
selected file: C:\ToLoad\RGP.txt
reading content....
ERROR loading file C:\ToLoad\RGP.txt: Access to the path 'C:\ToLoad\RGP.txt' is denied.
selected file: C:\ToLoad\RGP.dat
reading content....
Done....
```

EDIT #2:
I can't either create txt files, but .tx yes.
here is an example stacktrace:

```
ERROR creating file: Access to the path 'C:\ToLoad\NEW_test.txt' is denied.

StackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents)
   at TesterFilesaccess.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Are you shure that the files are not written at the same time? Or held open after last write by other application?

Comment: File may already be opened.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Probably another program keeping the file open after you asked to close it.  For example, antivirus, backup, cloud storage.  Try using FileStream with `FileShare.ReadWrite`, so you don't automatically fail if the file is still open elsewhere.

Comment: - I'm totally sure that no other program or user is opening the files: are simple files created ad hoc for test
- antivirus etc.... why only .txt and csv? and why notepad is not affected?

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that the two first files that fail have a ReadOnly attribute set?
Due to the description of Microsoft itself this results in an error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: That looks like a documentation bug, ReadAllText does only read and should work regardless of "read-only" attribute.

Comment: I’m not seeing that…

Comment: @DanielA.White: Look at the Exceptions section of the page, particularly UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: @BenVoigt yep now I see that

Comment: the file only differs by extension: are the same file copied and renamed; moreover, I'm simply reading the content